# What is the purpose of passing WindowProxy as the global this value?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, specifications

**Background**

The HTML spec introduces the concept of the [WindowProxy](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#windowproxy).

It says:

> A WindowProxy is an exotic object that wraps a Window ordinary object,
> indirecting most operations through to the wrapped object. Each
> browsing context has an associated WindowProxy object. When the
> browsing context is navigated, the Window object wrapped by the
> browsing context's associated WindowProxy object is changed.

The [WindowProxy](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#windowproxy) *platform object* is created when the [browsing context is created](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/document-sequences.html#creating-a-new-browsing-context) by the host, as defined in ECMAScript's [InitializeHostDefinedRealm](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) (step 8). It is directly set to be the global **this** value.

At that same point, the [Window](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/nav-history-apis.html#window) object is created, set to be the *global object*.

Through the ECMAScript spec, we see that whenever a lookup of an identifier happens, it first searches the environment record of the *current execution context*, and if not found continues out all the way out to the *Global Environment Record*, which in turn looks for the identifier on the *global object*.

As far as I can see, this set of operations never uses the global **this** value.

**Questions**

- Are there any operations in ECMAScript that use the global **this** value? If so, which?
- How exactly does setting the global **this** value to WindowProxy result in the desired proxy behavior?

**Edit**

- [This StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16092835/windowproxy-and-window-objects) answers the high-level purpose of WindowProxy. My question above is related to the ECMAScript spec and how exactly the *standard built-in* operations get delegated to the WindowProxy object, by virtue of it being the global **this** value.
- [Article](https://blog.whatwg.org/windowproxy-window-and-location) with some interesting, but vague, information not related to the ECMAScript spec.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can it somehow be seen in the ECMAScript spec though? One of the answers to the SO question you shared states: *iframe.contentWindow, or window.frames[0], or any other way of attempting to access a window, return a WindowProxy object, not a Window object*. If I look in the spec, an identifier lookup in global scope will indeed look for the binding on the global object, not on the global **this** value.

Comment: ECMAScript only describes the language, not the interfaces available.

Comment: @DanielA.White Yes, but ECMAScript does describe the language's operations. The HTML spec defined the WindowProxy interface and (via Web IDL operations) created a WindowProxy object and passed it to ECMAScript so it could be used as the global **this** value (see the spec links in the OP).

Comment: I doubt a `WindowProxy` would become the global object. your question is very confusing. it seems to juggle with `WindowProxy` and the global object.

Comment: @DanielA.White Could you please clarify, so I can fix it? The links I made to the specs should be quite descriptive. The spec is clear on the global object being `Window` and the global **this** value being `WindowProxy`. I am trying to understand how the global **this** value is used in ECMAScript, so I can understand how the proxy behavior that I quoted above from the HTML spec actually works under the hood.

Comment: It's not a duplicate of the other question. I changed the title to reflect the new body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is the only reason, but this at least allows to have the built-ins bound to the `WindowProxy` instead of on the `Window`, which may not be unique to the browsing-context.
This is done in https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-environment-records

> A Global Environment Record is logically a single record but it is specified as a composite encapsulating an [Object Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-environment-records) and a [Declarative Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-declarative-environment-records). The [Object Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-environment-records) has as its base object the [global object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object) of the associated [Realm Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#realm-record). This [global object](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object) is the value returned by the Global Environment Record's GetThisBinding concrete method. The [Object Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-environment-records) component of a Global Environment Record contains the bindings for all built-in globals (clause [19](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-global-object)) and all bindings introduced by a `FunctionDeclaration`, `GeneratorDeclaration`, `AsyncFunctionDeclaration`, `AsyncGeneratorDeclaration`, or `VariableStatement` contained in global code. The bindings for all other ECMAScript declarations in global code are contained in the [Declarative Environment Record](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-declarative-environment-records) component of the Global Environment Record.

You can see an example where this is observable in [this JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0tr1joLy/)* where we store the built-in function `eval` (hereafter `storedEval`) originating from a same-origin `<iframe>`.
From the `<iframe>`'s context we declare a global variable `window.foo = "first frame"`.
Calling `storedEval("this.foo")` from the parent document we get back the string `"first frame"`. This means that our `storedEval` function correctly is bound with the `<iframe>`'s context.
Then we navigate the `<iframe>` to a new document. At this point, the global object has been replaced, `this.foo` is undefined in the new `<iframe>` context.
Now, if we call again `storedEval("this.foo")` from the parent document, we also get `undefined`. And if we then set `window.foo` in the new `<iframe>` document, we'd get that new value.
This is because the built-in `eval` is bound to the `WindowProxy`, and not to the global `Window` object. Failing to do so, we'd keep a reference of the previous `Window`, even after its document has been navigated away.

<sub>* The example is outsourced because StackSnippet's null-orgined iframes don't allow cross-access, even from `srcdoc`</sub>

Comment: Really interesting, thanks! I will spend some time looking into it, and revert. My gut feeling is that accessing this in global scope will return WindowProxy. Whereas declaration instantiation in global scope actually properties adds to the global object, not the the global this value (according to the spec).

Comment: As a side-note: WHen a new global environment (GER) is created (https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-newglobalenvironment), the GER's object record is set to the global object, not to the global this value. When *GlobalDeclarationInstantiation* adds bindings for var declarations, it does so to whatever is stored in the GER's object record. As such, it does not make sense to me why a var in global scope would be added to WindowProxy (GlobalThisValue), and not to GER.[[ObjectRecord]].[[BindingObject]] (where the global object is stored).

Comment: Lastly, upon any identifier lookup, ResolveBinding will search up the ER chain, to that same object record (GER.[[ObjectRecord]].[[BindingObject]]), which holds the global object, and never look at the *GlobalThisValue*. Another seeming mismatch between the spec and the WindowProxy implementation.

Comment: I'm not sure to follow you here. In my example, there are two GERs, two Window global objects, but a single WindowProxy. So yes `ResolveBinding` will use its own global, but the built in functions will be bound to the one and only WindowProxy, so that when we extract one such built-in, `this` points to the "active" Window object, and not to the already dead one from where we extracted the function.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, Kaiido. I will spend more time on this as soon as I get the chance.  When searching the spec for the usage of the *GlobalThisValue*, I did not really find any other operations than the one which looks up the value of the keyword `this`. You mention that built-in functions are bound to WindowProxy, but not sure I see how. Built-in functions are created here: InitializeHostDefinedRealm (https://262.ecma-international.org/13.0/#sec-initializehostdefinedrealm) > CreateRealm > CreateIntrinsics (built-in functions are created and added to realmRec.[[Intrinsics]] record).

Comment: Then, the built-in functions are added as properties to the global object (not to the GlobalThisValue), here: InitializeHostDefinedRealm > SetRealmGlobalObject + SetDefaultGlobalBindings. I can't see it adding those built-in functions to the GlobalThisValue anywhere. I might be missing something?

Comment: Why would anything be added to the thisValue? Anyway at the time the environment record is built the WindowProxy will redirect to the same global. This matters only when the global object isn't the Window associated with the WindowProxy anymore. In that case we want  `this` to point to the new active Window object. Setting the thisValue to the WindowProxy allows just that.

Comment: Maybe [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/352n69z4/) is clearer? If you check your browser's console (and not the one from jsfiddle), and inspect the logged Window object, you'll see that what the console received as `this` from the extracted function was actually the WindowProxy and not the global Window: its live representation will have a `.foo` property holding `"second frame"`, even though at the time it got logged that value was `"first frame"` and `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks, let me check it out. We know from the HTML spec that the WindowProxy object is passed into realm initialization as the global this value, and the Window object is passed in as the global object. The ECMAScript spec, which takes over at this point (called by HTML spec), stores the global object (Window) into GER.[[Object record]].[[BindingRecord]], and the global this value (WindowProxy) will be saved into GER.[[GlobalThisValue]]. I am trying to find out from the ECMAScript spec when/where that global this value is used, which seems to be only when accessing this in global code.